# Why isn't the below procedure returning accurate value for number of parameters?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I wrote the below procedure to retrieve the number of parameters in a stored procedure.But it doesn't return accurate values and also some of the procedures don't appear in the quesry I have written.How can I edit this to list all the procedures and return their number of parameters?

```
CREATE PROC test_op @name varchar(100), @count int OUTPUT
AS
SELECT  @count =COUNT (INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS.PARAMETER_NAME)
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS
GROUP BY INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS.SPECIFIC_NAME,INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA

DECLARE @count1 int
EXEC test_op usp_GetDBTime, @count=@count1 OUTPUT
Print @count1
```

Comment: You don't use `@name` in there...

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by the parameter name, so the query returns multiple values.  One of them is getting assigned to the output variable.

If you want the number for a single procedure, then use `where` instead of `group by`:

```
CREATE PROC test_op (
    @name varchar(100),
    @count int OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  @count =COUNT(p.PARAMETER_NAME)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS p
    WHERE p.SPECIFIC_NAME = @name;
END;

DECLARE @count1 int;
EXEC test_op 'usp_GetDBTime', @count = @count1 OUTPUT
Print @count1;
```

You might want to include the schema name in the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The most significant issue is that you don't filter by `@name`. However, even inside that, you could have problems with duplicate names in different schemas. This should work reasonably reliably - addressing both of those issues, while also supporting a better range of `@name` formats (`'Foo'` vs `'dbo.Foo'`, etc):

```
ALTER PROC test_op @name sysname -- or CREATE the first time
AS
DECLARE @id int = OBJECT_ID(@name);
DECLARE @schema sysname = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@id);
SET @name = OBJECT_NAME(@id);
RETURN (
    SELECT COUNT(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS.PARAMETER_NAME)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS
    WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME = @name AND SPECIFIC_SCHEMA = @schema)
GO
DECLARE @count1 int;
EXEC @count1 = test_op 'test_op' -- etc
Print @count1
```